# ¿Comó puedo crear un contador descendente en android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Estoy creando una app con autenticación por telefono en kotlin con firebase
me gustaría poder implementar un contador de 60 segundos a 0 para mostrar una opción de reenviar mensaje pero no encuentro como implementar el contador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontre la solución con el siguiente código que leí en la documentación de Android [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) les comparto el código por si a alguien le funciona!:

```
val contResendMsg : TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_send_msg)

    object: CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished:Long) {
            contResendMsg.text = "Reenviar código en ... " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            contResendMsg.text = "Volver a enviar"
        }
    }.start()
```